# Using jquery to toggle an element that is loaded through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, toggle

I have a .php which loads into a div through ajax. Within this .php, I have a `<a href>` link which is supposed to toggle the next `<p>`, show/hide. But when I put the jQuery code in the .php itself, it didn't work. So I realized I might have to put the jQuery code into the receiving .php which has the ajax - where the user will see the `<a href>` to show/hide the `<p>`. But it doesn't seem to do anything. Here's the html:

```
echo "<div><a class=\"exp\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\">View explanation: </a>";
echo "<p class=\"pexp\" style=\"display:none;\">";
echo $tfeedback;
echo "</p></div>";
```

jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.exp').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop href()
    $(this).next().toggle();      
});
    });
</script>
```

The $tfeedback is string - I've checked to make sure it is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please try this code hope it helps you......

$(document).delegate('.exp','click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop href()
   if($(this).next().css('display')=='block'){
    $(this).next().hide();
}else{
    $(this).next().show();
     }   
});

OR

$(document).on('click', '.exp', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop href()
    if($(this).next().css('display')=='block'){
    $(this).next().hide();
}else{
    $(this).next().show();
     }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably executing the code in the second snippet before the anchor and paragraph have been loaded via AJAX. At this stage there is no element that matches `.exp`, so the collection `$('.exp')` is empty.

The solution is to delegate to an ancestor that is already present:

```
$(document).on('click', '.exp', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop href()
    $(this).next().toggle();      
});
```

Comment: @OmairVaiyani I can't see a `View explanation` link anywhere.

Comment: Sorry wrong link, updated it: http://www.mycqs.com/mcqs/Medical/Biochemistry/Blood/?mcq_src=4